# debugging with gdb - jump bug?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I am debugging a simple program in gdb and came across this weird behaviour:

[image]

As you can see the jmp should go to `0x5555555549b9`. However in the next step (there is a ni between the two x/5i) I end up at `0x55555555493f` instead. How could this be happening?

Because of this wrong jump, a bit later I just get a segfault. This only happens when debugging the program in gdb, without gdb it runs through that jmp nicely.

I do not have the source for it. Any idea though why this is happening?!

Comment: Tried using stepi (just to check gdb does not see this as some weird function call)?